# Root cause analysis of web server performance problems

Tags: asp.net, performance, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, newrelic

We have an ASP.NET web application deployed in Azure App Service and using Application Insights for logging and New Relic as a monitoring tool.

Often I am investigating slow response times and what I find the most difficult is identifying the root cause.

In New Relic, I can see all the endpoints got slower:

[image]

But there was probably one endpoint which got hit by expensive requests, leading to a CPU utilization spike, manifesting as slow response times for every endpoint.

Sometimes it's pretty clear - one endpoint might get a burst of traffic, so it stands out. But often times it's not about the throughput, it's about what those requests look like.

Are there some established analytical or statistical methods of figuring out the root cause in cases like this? I can imagine it might involve getting a profiler snapshot of the running application, analyzing the web server logs etc.

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands of articles and blog posts about troubleshooting ASP.NET applications. Google is your friend.

Comment: Sure there are. What I'm looking for is a rigorous approach to distinguishing between causes and symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the best approach for performance issues is Profiling, so you can identify which part of your application is spending the most time.

App Service Diagnostics has a built-in Profiler for ASP.NET Web Apps.

In the Portal, navigate to your Web App, open the Diagnose and Solve problems blade from the left menu, and search for **Collect .NET Profiler Trace**.

You can also Collect **Memory Dump** and **Network Trace** which might also help in your case.

See this [blog post](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/06/06/App-Service-Diagnostics-Profiling-an-ASP.NET-Web-App-on-Azure-App-Service.html) for details on how to collect and understand the Analysis Report.

Also, since you have Application Insights, you can also run Profiler for your production application from there, which will capture the data automatically at scale without negatively affecting your users.

See: [Profile production applications in Azure with Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler-overview#view-profiler-data)

Once you identify which layer causing the latency, you can take from there to debug and optimize your code/setup.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to profile the web app, it's useful especially when you can expect to capture the degraded performance going forward. What I am more interested in is analyzing an incident after it happens, without an obvious way to reproduce it. You have web request logs, transaction traces etc., but not the profiler snapshot. How do you then establish the root cause? Btw. we don't use the Application Insights profiler, it doesn't play well with New Relic because of the Always On settings.